# Chrome no-longer pre-selects existing text in address bar when opening new tab

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs, selection, address-bar

Sometime relatively recently (within past month probably), Chrome changed its behavior when opening a new tab.

Previously when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a tab, it would pre-select whatever was in the address bar so I could start typing immediately and wipe out what was in there.

Now, it will set the cursor at the beginning of whatever is there w/o anything selected.

I'm used to hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then immediately typing in a search and now its pretty annoying b/c I end up w/something like this

[image: Chrome address bar]

This doesn't happen on my other computers, so I'm guessing some local setting changed as opposed to a universal behavior change.  It annoys me enough that I've tried reinstalling chrome to no avail.

Any ideas on what could've caused this/how to fix it?

I'm using v61.0.3163.100(64bit)

Comment: So why do you have anything in the address bar of a new tab? If you usually type something in there, set your default new tab to about:blank.

Comment: I'm using an extension which goes to chrome://apps/ by default.  This is handy b/c even though I usually don't use those (I'm usually just typing in a search), I frequently do want one of the google "apps" and this is a quick way to get to them.

It used to select the chrome://apps text however, which it isn't doing anymore.

I'd honestly forgotten that was an extension and just figured it was a built-in feature of Chrome...to set what a new tab went to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same version and this was driving me crazy. I discovered the culprit on my PC: the Replace New Tab Page extension. After disabling it, a new tab won't prefill anything in the address bar.

Comment: Yep, this was my problem, although I was using a different extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/show-apps-in-new-tab/nohbdifokmdgjcbbeobglcbaifinhfip?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog